# Find a homeomorphism, topological conjugation, between two matrices that are not similar.

Tags: calculus, general-topology, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I need to find a homeomorphism, topological conjugation $h:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ tal que $h(\phi^t(x))=\psi^t(h(x))$, between the two flows $\phi^t(x)=e^{tA}x$ and $\psi^ t(x)=e^{tB}x$, where
$$
 A=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}\quad\text{ and }\quad B=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & -1 \\
1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Firstly, I must say that there is such a conjugation $h$ since both systems ($x'=Ax$ and $x'=Bx$) have the same stability index (or are attractors). Second, these two matrices are not similar matrices (I already verified it), I tried to find homeomorphism $h$ with the help of the proof of the theorem that ensures its existence, but I couldn't, since in one part of that proof the implicit function theorem is used.\
The flows are:
$$
\phi^t(x,y)=e^{-t}(x,y) \quad\text{and}\quad \psi^t(x,y)=e^{-t}(x\cos(t)-y\sin(t),x\sin(t)+y\cos(t)),
$$
the homeomorphism $h$ must not depend on the parameter $t$.

Any help or suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In terms of a scalar complex DE, $z_1'=-z_1$ and $z_2'=(-1+i)z_2$, would $z_2=z_1e^{i\ln|z_1|}$ work?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you mean.